# In Java Jframe open another JFrame but JFrame show nothing

Tags: java

i do a java program with Eclipse Window Builder, there got 2 class

1. Login.java
2. Menu.java

so when username and password is matched , then the Login.java will close and Menu.java will open

in my code, i try using

```
if(true)
{   
       Menu menu = new Menu();
       menu.setVisible(true);
       login.dispose();
}
else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Username or Password",    "Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

and run the Login.java, Menu.java will show, but in very mini size and when i expand it, Menu.java is nothing contain.

i watched some video tutorial on youtube, they teach in this way but when i try is not working, hope somebody can help , thank a lot.

Comment: Does `Menu` extend `JFrame`? Have you imported the correct `Menu` class?

Comment: Does `Menu` class extend `JFrame`?

Comment: Also `if(true)` isn't really effective... you will always end up in the `if` clause, because you don't check anything.

Comment: Menu is no extend JFrame. is need to extend, i using window builder to create this two classes.

Comment: "if (true)" is just an example, sorry i din't mention in my post.

Comment: i put "extends JFrame" in Menu.java, but when Menu.java display is show nothing contains.

Comment: That's because, you didn't add any components to your frame. The problem now lies in your `Menu` class.

Comment: thank your reply, but i still confusing, my Menu.java is design complete, i do need add again the component of frame Menu ?

Comment: What does `Login` extend? I hope it's not `JFrame`.

Comment: Login does not extend any.

Comment: Then you have to update the question with your code. Show the relevant parts from `Login` and `Menu` and specify what does not work, which line throws an error and what the error is.

Comment: updated already. is need pass the reference from menu,java to login.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Menu menu= new Menu();
menu.frame.setVisible(true);
```